# Purpose of package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

All tutorials agree that `project.json` should include:

```json
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": 
{ 
    "type":"build", 
    "version":"1.0.0-preview2-final" 
}
```

I have never included it, and have never had a problem.

I only include

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore"
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite"   (or Sqlserver)
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools"
```

What does this package do? Why can I exclude it without problems?

---

UPDATE: see comments in accepted answer to figure out which package to import in which scenario.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` contains all the design-time logic for Entity Framework Core. It's the code that all of the various tools (PMC cmdlets like `Add-Migration`, `dotnet ef` & `ef.exe`) call into.

If you don't use Migrations or Reverse Engineering, you don't need it.

And when you do need it, we encourage `PrivateAssets="All"` so it doesn't get published to the server where you almost certainly won't need it.

Comment: I don't use PMC, but I do use the CLI tools (`dotnet ef foo bar`) for migrations. And don't have a problem. Weird! Is that maybe because I include  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`?

Comment: Yes. EFCore.Tools will pull in EFCore.Design for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is finally making sense! So one last thing: what is the difference between `EFCore.Design` and `EFCore.Tools`? The tutorials/examples never explain, they only say to import both. All I want is the CLI tools.

Comment: EFCore.Tools is the PMC commands. (And any future tooling we might add that doesn't require its own package like the CLI tools.)

Comment: Summary for everyone else: If you want PMC commands then import `EFCore.Tools`. If you want the CLI tools then import `EFCore.Design`. If you want both then only import `EFCore.Tools`.

Comment: Any idea why it isn't just a dependency of the CLI tools so that it could be a pure global tool? Seems odd

Comment: @MarkAdamson The traditional approach is to make it part of the main EF package, but we wanted to be more modular and not make those not using it pay the extra cost. It's not part of the tool because the tool can work against any version of EF, but the design package only works against the version of EF it's compiled against. The EF Core Power Tools include a copy for every version to work without requiring it to be installed into the project, but that didn't seem sustainable for the CLI tool.