# .NET EF in Dotnet 6 installed, but when calling it it tells me command or file was not found

Tags: .net, entity-framework, migration, apple-m1, .net-6.0

I did install dotnet ef using this command

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

It returned

```
Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.
```

I assume that it is correctly installed.

When running the command below inside my project

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

it returns

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Dotnet SDK version: 6.0.101
Device: Macbook Air M1

NB: I tried using the x64 version of dotnet via Rosetta. No luck, the same issue persists.

How to fix it?

Comment: I think you should add also package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574122/purpose-of-package-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-design

Comment: @AchoVasilev it is already installed

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

This fixes the problem permanently:

```
dotnet tool uninstall dotnet-ef -g
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef -a arm64 -g
```

---

You can also try installing ef tool locally

CD to your source directory then:

```
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install  dotnet-ef
```

Comment: This has fixed my issue. I've been struggling for like 3 hours to use dotnet ef on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This doesnt fix the issue (as you have to do it for every project again and again) but works as a work-around. Thanks.

Comment: To fix it permanently try this: dotnet tool install -g -a arm64

Answer (score 0):

The version 6 of this tool doesn't work for some reason.

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef
```

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5
```

```
cat << \EOF >> ~/.zprofile
# Add .NET Core SDK tools
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/jp/.dotnet/tools"
EOF
```

```
zsh -l
```

```
nano .zshrc
```

then add to the start of the file this `/Users/jp/.dotnet/tools`.
It should look something like this

```
export PATH=/Users/yourusername/.dotnet/tools:/opt/homebrew/bin:...
```

Then

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue on Windows 10. Even if dotnet-ef was installed successfully in global environment, it was not found even if my user specific path indeed contained `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools`.

Other things related to VS Code lieke `code -r <projectpath>` were also not working properly.

I realized, my user specific path variable was not merged with system path. Perhaps my **system path** was **too long** (about 4200 characters)?

So my solution was to **significantly** shorten the system path by removing entries not longer required.

A second step was to use regedit to convert system path from "REG_SZ" type into "REG_EXPAND_SZ" type and substitute long and repeated parts.

Well, it works for me perfectly.