# EntityFrameworkCore nuget packages confusion in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a web application / api using the dot net core.

for the database I choose Microsoft **SqlServer**, and **EntityFrameworkCore** as **ORM**

in previous versions like Asp.Net MVC 5 i used like this:

`Install-Package EntityFramework`

and i was able to work with Migrations, DbContexts ...

but now with dot net core I saw that I have to install multiple EntityFramework nuget packages, I saw this in multiple tutorials and also in real world.

developers installing the following packages without explaining why:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

I googled it so it turns out that I need only these:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

because the Tools package brings up the Design package from this post : [Purpose of package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574122/purpose-of-package-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-design)

the question is which packages do we need in dot net core to use entityframeworkcore in our project?

Comment: just edited the post, so actually i'm confused and i want to understand wich one is true about the packages wich i need  to use entityframeworkcore, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver
```

(It depends on .Relational)

If you need to run EF Core commands in VS Package Manger console install:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

If you want the dotnet CLI EF Core tools run:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Comment: thanks a lot make sence now

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net 5 you need to specify the version that the package is for.

But first you need to open the package manager console. That is from View->Other Windows->Package Manager Console. There you need to make sure that the default project is the project you want to work with.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IWRJ.png)

Then run these commands in the package manager console:

1.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 5.0
```

2. 

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 5.0
```

3. 

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
```

(for the SqlServer.Design you don't need to specify the version)

(if you are using .net 6 just remove the "-Version 5.0" from the commands)